# node js file upload download and streaming data

Tags: node.js

I have been reading about Node and how it is single threaded. If I have a large file(500mb) to upload to server or download the file from a server , I am guessing this cannot happen as asynchronous at the server side . Is this a bad use case to use nodejs in this scenario ? or is there a solution where this can be done without blocking the event loop ?

Answer (score 0):

There's one *user thread* but there are other threads in node.

Most IO operations are done for you behind the scene and you only act on events. Typically, you'll receive events with chunks of data and, if other requests happen at the same time, they may be interlaced with other events. If you don't do a lot in the main thread (which is usually the case), there's no reason your program blocks during an upload.

Comment: While downloading the call back handler will be executed for a long time until all the data will be written to the client . Will that not block the event loop since event loop will be executing the call back handler ?

Comment: That's not really a loop in your script : your event handler is called many times with the data of this connection but in between your other event handlers can be called too.